# Maximum flow problem with flow into two non-adjacent nodes either be simultaneously greater than 0 or all 0s

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have a directed graph that I want to find a maximum flow. But there are two non-adjacent nodes, say $a$ and $b$, that I want either the flows coming into $a$ and $b$ are simultaneously greater than $0$, or simultaneously $0$. I know max flow algorithm can be extended to edge disjoint, node disjoint and edge demand problems, but the kind of constraint I described above does not seem to have a solution. I tried to add an extra node, say $c$, and then add edges from $a$ to $c$, $b$ to $c$, and $c$ to the sink $t$, and then converted it to some sort of the mentioned extensions, but it seems hopeless.

Edit: directed graph, the flow can be integers, but it is not required.

Comment: Do you require flows to be integers?

Comment: And is your graph directed?

Comment: Yes it is directed. And the flow can be integer, but it is not required.

Comment: Do you have exactly one pair of nodes with this constraint, or do you need to handle many such constraints at once?

Answer (score 0):

With such constraints it is possible that there *is no maximum flow*, but instead an upper limit that can be approached but not reached exactly. Consider  for example:

```
              *-------*Sink
             / \     /
        *   /   b   /
       / \ /     \ /
Source*---a-------*
```

where every edge goes from left to right and has a capacity of $1$.

You can't have any flow at all unless something flows into $a$, so there must be *some* flow through the diagonal that has $b$ on it. But the total flow you can get is exactly $2$ *minus* that diagonal flow, so you can *approach* a flow of $2$ by choosing the flow through $b$ as small as you want, as long as it is positive.

The magnitude of this limiting flow is easy enough to find, though:

1. First remove both $a$ and $b$ from the graph and find a maximum flow through what is left. This fallback solution will certainly satisfy your condition.
2. Now find a new maximum flow through the entire graph, ignoring your additional condition. Call the result the "optimistic" solution.
3. If the optimistic solution *either* satisfies your condition *or* it is no better than the fallback solution, then we're done: either way we know a maximal flow that satisfies your condition.
4. Otherwise, suppose without loss of generality that $a$ has flow in the optimistic solution but $b$ hasn't.
5. Construct the residual network (like in the Ford-Fulkerson method) corresponding to the optimistic solution. See if it contains any *cycle* that includes $b$. If it does, you can add half of that cycle to the optimistic solution, and get one with the same total flow, but positive flow into both $a$ and $b$.
6. Otherwise, check there is *any* path from the source to $b$ to the sink. If not, no flow through $b$ is possible, so go back to the fallback solution instead.
7. Otherwise, we can at least *approach* the flow from the optimistic solution arbitarily well. Namely: Multiply all flows by $1-\varepsilon$ for some sufficiently small $\varepsilon$. Now all edges are in play again, and you can add a small "tickle flow" through $b$ to make it meet your condition.

If you require that flows are integers, the approximation won't work, of course. Instead, if $a$ has a total flow of $1$ in the optimistic solution, the search for a correction in step (5) needs to be modified to avoid taking that flow away. This is probably easiest to do by splitting $a$ into an input and an output node, with an edge between them whose back-edge you *omit* from the residual network. (And if you then don't find a solution, then the fallback solution is in fact best possible).

Comment: Thanks very much. That is very helpful! Now what if the flow must be integers? According to your answer, I am now thinking maybe I should model the problem at hand as an integer maximum flow problem.

Comment: @Ouyang: I was just adding some thoughts about that to the end of the answer.